# Webservice SOAP usa apenas XML?

Tags: xml, web-service, rest, soap, restful

Trabalhando algum tempo com `webservice` para aplicação móvel percebi que `SOAP` usa `XML`  e `REST` usa `JSON`. Utilizando `SOAP` significa que tenho que usar somente `XML`?

Answer (score 6):

Algumas questões:

> Utilizando SOAP significa que tenho que usar somente XML?

Sim, SOAP por definição usa XML como formato de comunicação, não existe um maneira de alterar isso.

> Então não existe um forma de usar JSON com SOAP?

Sim em teoria existe, como o formato de mensagem é XML, você pode adicionar sua string de representação de um JSON dentro de uma tag CDATA. Embora seja uma técnica não muito convencional ainda assim em teoria é possível.

> É aconselhável usar JSON na mensagem XML do SOAP?

Não em teoria, minha tese é se você precisa utilizar em muitos momentos o JSON para contornar as restrições/limitações do XML então porque não eliminar o SOAP também. JSON é originalmente utilizado para chamadas em ajax o que provavelmente torna o SOAP uma ferramenta muito rígida para as necessidades das pessoas.
Cabe a você decidir se o fato da necessidade recorrente de utilizar JSON como formato de comunicação não torna o REST a melhor opção para desenvolver seus webservices.